# My external javascript isn't working properlly, but internally it is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i'm trying to create a javascript presentation for a website i'm working on. It's very basic and is mainly using one of the guides on w3schools. The presentation works fine when i have the javascript internally, however when using it externally, it loads all the pictures in a list, however when you press the "next" button, they all disappear and the presentation works correctly.
[here is the page on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozOoY.png)

below is the HTML

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/slide.js"></script>



           <div class="slideshowcontainer">  
             <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace1.jpg" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace2.jpg" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace3.jpg" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace4.jpg" style="width:500px" "height:400px">

  <button class="left-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="right-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

i am not very familiar with javascript, however i have tried doing window.onload and document.onload and also surrounding it with function.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Make sure your external script is either loaded at the end of the `<body>` tag or has the `defer` attribute.

Comment: Where did you put your script?

Comment: can you show us how you've loaded your external javascript file?

Comment: in a sub file, using this link in the head

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/slide.js"></script>

Comment: Sounds like the JS file isn't loading on the second page?

Answer (score 0):

Your external JS should be inside body tag like this `<script src="filename.js"></script>`

Comment: inside the body? i used this <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/slide.js"></script> inside the head.

edit: just tried moving it from head to body, no change, all the pictures still display before clicking on the next button

Comment: @finH That should be fine.

Comment: That's also okay, make sure you have correct path. What is the output in the console ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showDivs (slide.js:17)
    at slide.js:3

i get this error, its just strange that when i run the exact same javascript internally the presentation is fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dom is loaded before you call showDivs.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  showDivs(slideIndex);
});

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
 <div class="slideshowcontainer">  
   <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace1.jpg" alt="1" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace2.jpg" alt="2" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace3.jpg" alt="3" style="width:500px" "height:400px">
  <img class="slideshow" src="../images/formalplace4.jpg" alt="4" style="width:500px" "height:400px">

  <button class="left-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="right-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this did it! Thank you very much, just for my understanding, was the issue that the DOM wasnt loaded into the script first, so it couldnt call it on load?

Comment: @finH Because your script tag was placed in the <head> it executed before the html in the body was loaded. Your script then called the showDivs function. This function searches for the elements with the class "slideshow". Since these elements where not loaded yet, it could not find them.

Answer (score 0):

As @gyre pointed out, you may use the `defer` attribute while including your external JavaScript file.

So, this will work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/slide.js" defer></script>
```